# server error 500, while entering wrong address in Laravel 5

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.0 project. When I enter wrong link on locahost, Laravel redirects me to custom error template, using this code on `app\Exceptions\Handler.php.`

```
protected $dontReport = [
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
];

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($this->isHttpException($e)){
        switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {
            case '404':
                \Log::error($e);
                return \Response::view('error');
                break;

            case '500':
                \Log::error($exception);
                return \Response::view('error');
                break;

            default:
                return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

After moving my laravel project to shared Hosting (not Linux) site does not redirect me to custom error template `(views/error.blade.php)`, while entering wrong address which does not exist in `app/http/routes.php`. I tried many solutions, configured `.htaccess` file, but did not get a result. Error.log is empty. Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried remove `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` lines. In this case I can get 404 error page, but it brings me problems:

1) Laravel will not recognize aliases, if exists. For example (www.site.com/news)

2) Laravel will not send post requests to another page, for example (www.site.com/post)

3) Laravel will not display custom error template `(views/error.blade.php)` if I type wrong address, which not exists in `app/http/routes.php,` For example (www.site.com/wrong)

For accessing site without public, I made some changes:
1) I moved all files from `public_html`, except `public folder` to `applicaton` folder. Then, moved files from `public` folder into `public_html`.

2) Little changes in `index.php`

before:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

after:

```
require __DIR__.'/application/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/application/bootstrap/app.php';
```

My files structure in `public_html`:

```
application
    app (inside application folder)
    server.php (inside application folder)
.htaccess
index.php
```

Comment: Do you have access to the SSH terminal of the server?

Comment: Since your code is essentially correct in general, try turning on the app debug mode, and access those inexistent routes. There may be errors that are preventing laravel from displaying these 404 views.

Comment: I turned on and app/storage/error.log is empty. I moved my files to linux server( debian8) and worked. But in shared hosting still problems.

Comment: Make sure laravel has permissions to write to `app/storage/error.log`. Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: I need working version on shared hosting, i changed permission to 777 on storage folder, but no result :(

Comment: I solved the problem :) it was with `app/exceptions/handler.php`. It was laravel's 5.1 file :) I accidentally replaced 5.0 `handler.php` with 5.1 `handler.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally replaced laravel 5.0 `handler.php` to laravel 5.1 `handler.php`.

I edited `protected $dontReport` file.

**before**

```
protected $dontReport = [
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
];
```

**after**

```
protected $dontReport = [
    'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'
];
```